# Spring Application Listener - ContextRefreshedEvent java:comp/env/jdbc/db not found

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to do some database cleanup when the application first starts.
First I have defined my JNDI connection as follows:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
            resource.setName("jdbc/myDataSource");
            resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
            resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "your.db.Driver");
            resource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:yourDb");

            context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
        }
    };
}
```

Then I wish to retrieve the resource in the ApplicationListener ContextRefreshedEvent, the ApplicationListener implementation is as follows:

```
@Component
public class StartupConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
{
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = event.getApplicationContext();

        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource");
        ...
    }

}
```

The problem is that it is unable to find java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource, I have tested using various events and the only event in which this works is in the `RequestHandledEvent` which I do not think its a good solution.

Comment: Why are you even doing a lookup in that code? You should let spring do that and simply inject it. However why even use a JNDI resource in this case you could get the same functionality without using JNDI here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer in the following stack overflow question
stackoverflow.com/questions/27822619

I will quote Andy Wilkinson

> Tomcat uses the thread's context class loader to determine the JNDI context to perform the lookup against. If the thread context class loader isn't the web app classloader then the JNDI context is empty, hence the lookup failure.

And the suggested fix by Andy Wilkinson

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

    @Override
    protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
            Tomcat tomcat) {
        tomcat.enableNaming();
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer container = 
                super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        for (Container child: container.getTomcat().getHost().findChildren()) {
            if (child instanceof Context) {
                ClassLoader contextClassLoader = 
                        ((Context)child).getLoader().getClassLoader();
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextClassLoader);
                break;
            }
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
        resource.setName("jdbc/myDataSource");
        resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
        resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "your.db.Driver");
        resource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:yourDb");

        context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
    }
};
}
```